# Nexus Central local storage missing maven jars

Tags: maven, build, pom.xml, nexus, ear

I am currently using Nexus, but i'm pretty new to it.

I'm trying to build an EAR project and i'm getting the error below.

http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/groups/public  is the default Public Group repository which includes Central, and within Central, the version 2.2.1 versions of the org.apache.maven artifacts are there remotely.

However, if i look at the local storage, it's not there, like the errors suggest.

I thought that during the build, it would update the local storage with the necessary files.  I tried -U force updates already.

Any pointers are appreciated

John.

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.10:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) @ my-apps.ear ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.9 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.22 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to getClass for org.apache.maven.plugin.ear.GenerateApplicationXmlMojo
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.089 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-27T03:48:10+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/107M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.10:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) on project my-apps.ear: Execution default-generate-application-xml of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.10:generate-application-xml failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.10 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.2.1, org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.6, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:2.9, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.20, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.3, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.22: Failure to find org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1 in http://localhost:8080/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: did you try to expire cache /Rebuild Metadata?

Comment: Does Nexus has access to Maven Central ? Proxy / Firewall configuration?

Comment: I have tried to expire the cache, via Nexus

Comment: I forgot to mention also, Nexus should have access to central because there are jars in the local storage, for some of the versions.   For example, for org.apache.maven.maven-project,  i have 2 versioned folders, but not all of them, when you compare it with the onlne repository.  Not sure why it's able to get some and not all

Comment: There are lots of reasons why this might be happening, but most likely you have a network problem and Nexus can't reach https://repo1.maven.org.  Check your logs.  See here for other troubleshooting tips: https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464518-Troubleshooting-Artifact-Download-Failures

Comment: @JohnG., Please share your maven settings.xml file?